# in html file, how do I convert DateTime format to Hrs:Min?

Tags: python, json, api, datetime, typeconverter

I'm running an API REQUEST to retrieve schedules for classes. Here is my code below in the index.html file

```
{% for class in listofclasses %}
    <div class="list-classes"><strong>{{ class.ClassDescription.Name }}</strong> with {{ class.Staff.FirstName }} at {{ class.StartDateTime }} </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

In the code above, the class.StartDateTime will retrieve the time as follows: 2020-03-30T18:00:00

How would I convert that to something like **6:00pm**? Or **3/30 at 6:00pm**?

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
{% for class in listofclasses %}
    <div class="list-classes"><strong>{{ class.ClassDescription.Name }}</strong> with {{ class.Staff.FirstName }} at {{ class.StartDateTime|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }} </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Howabout...

```
import datetime
input_time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-20T18:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
new_time_date = input_time_date.strftime('%m/%d at %I:%M%p').replace('at 0', 'at ')
new_time_only = input_time_date.strftime('%I:%M%p').lstrip('0')
print(new_time_date)
print(new_time_only)
```

03/20 at 6:00PM

6:00PM

Comment: You need to convert the date/time format before sending it to your template.

Comment: Also, I suggest not using "class" as a variable name.  "class" is a reserved word.